# Connecting to Windows share "Name not unique on network"

Tags: debian, smb, windows-domain, cifs

I'm trying to connect from a stock Debian 8 or 9 Desktop to a Windows shared folder, by clicking "Connect to Server" from Nautilus or Cinnamon using a Server Name:

```
smb://servername/shared
```

which works, as I'm prompted to type in my Username / Domain / Password. However, I then get an error message:

> **Could not display "smb://servername/shared/".**
>   Error: Failed to mount Windows share: Name not unique on network
>   Please select another viewer and try again.

I'm not sure which name is not unique. How can I connect to this Windows shared folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround rather than a complete answer. I was able to access the server by IP, so instead of `smb://servername/shared` use `smb://server_ip/shared`

Comment: I suspect a promising solution might be found by using `net join` from samba, but this requires admin privileges on AD, which I do not have, and I'm hesitant to keep testing since I have the above workaround ... but maybe I'll come back to it at some point.

Comment: This is a fine working solution for now. I'm using `host servername` to get the IP address of the server.